# LXC - using generated apparmor profiles, but apparmor status shows unconfined

Tags: lxc, apparmor, userns

I have been using unprivileged `lxc` containers (running as root but with user namespaces) using the following config to make use of apparmor:

```
lxc.apparmor.profile = generated
lxc.apparmor.allow_nesting = 1
```

When the containers are running, I see an apparmor profile does get generated, and that it's loaded in syslog. For example:

```
Jan 15 04:00:16 localhost kernel: [1315978.637961] audit: type=1400 audit(1673776816.182:395): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" profile="/usr/bin/lxc-start" name="lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>" pid=2951275 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 15 04:00:34 localhost kernel: [1315996.830889] audit: type=1400 audit(1673776834.374:396): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="/usr/bin/lxc-start" name="lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>" pid=2953280 comm="apparmor_parser"


ls -la '/var/lib/lxc/apache/apparmor/lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>'
-rw------- 1 root root 38155 Jan 15 04:00 'lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>'
```

However, when I run `aa-status`, I get the following output:

```
   /usr/bin/busybox (2954962) lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>//&:lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>:unconfined
   /usr/sbin/sshd (2956272) lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>//&:lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>:unconfined
   /usr/sbin/httpd (2956340) lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>//&:lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>:unconfined
   /usr/sbin/httpd (2956353) lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>//&:lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>:unconfined
   /usr/sbin/httpd (2956363) lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>//&:lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>:unconfined
   /usr/bin/busybox (2956473) lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>//&:lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>:unconfined
```

If I understand correctly, it's telling me that there are two apparmor profiles being applied, `lxc-apache_</var/lib/lxc>//&` and `lxc-apache_<-var-lib-lxc>:unconfined`.

I'm unsure what this means when it seems to be telling me that loading the same profile a second time in `unconfined` mode. Is this a consequence of using `nesting` and/or `userns`?

Because the container is running unprivileged I'm not concerned about the security of the container but rather I'm interested in how AppArmor is working in this scenario.